# jQuery AutoComplete : Make suggestions appear over the text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the Jquery autocomplete plugin found here : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

It's working fine but the auto complete hints appears as a drop-down list whereas I want it to appear as drop-up ( Don't know if its the right word, but I want the hits to appear over the text box not below it).

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default position settings for JQuery UI autocomplete include:

```
 position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        collision: "none"
    },
```

You can probably provide the following to your call:

```
$('.whatever').autocomplete({
   position: {
       my: "left bottom",
       at: "left top",
   });
```

Comment: Yea figured that out :)

Comment: @Edward: Thanks. That was from memory, not a fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery Ui autocomplete [`position`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position) option; the option allows you to set the position of the suggestions list using the jQuery UI position utility.

Quick reference:

> Identifies the position of the suggestions menu in relation to the
>   associated input element. The of option defaults to the input element,
>   but you can specify another element to position against. You can refer
>   to the jQuery UI Position utility for more details about the various
>   options.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"];

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        position: {
            my: "left bottom",
            at: "left top",
        }
    });

});
```

Worging demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/KQdg8/

Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-position